# Different result when evaluating tflite model from python and from android

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, keras

I've trained a model using keras (in google colab), then I've converted the keras h5 file to tflite using `TFLiteConverter` (also in google colab) by using this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tflite_converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(<KERAS_H5_MODEL_PATH>)

tflite_model = tflite_converter.convert()

with open(<KERAS_TFLITE_DEST_PATH>, 'wb') as tflite_model_file:
    tflite_model_file.write(tflite_model)
```

After that, I've run the tflite model (in google colab also):

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Load TFLite model and allocate tensors.
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path=tflite_model_path)
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'], <INPUT_DATA>)

interpreter.invoke()

output = [interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0], interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0]]
```

However, when I run the tflite model in an android app (using the same input data) y get different outputs:

(This code is based on [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android) from tensorflow)

```java
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assets.openFd(<MODEL_FILENAME>);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
MappedByteBuffer model = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);

Interpreter.Options interpreterOptions = new Interpreter.Options().setNumThreads(NUM_THREADS).setAllowFp16PrecisionForFp32(Boolean.FALSE);
tfLite = new Interpreter(model, interpreterOptions);

float[][][][] floatValues = new float[1][inputSize][inputSize][3];

// floatValues array is initialized with the same values as in python code above

Object[] inputArray = {floatValues};

output1 = new float[1][8][8][18];
output2 = new float[1][16][16][18];

Map<Integer, Object> outputMap = new HashMap<>();
outputMap.put(0, output1);
outputMap.put(1, output2);

tfLite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputArray, outputMap);
```

The output values I get in the android code have nothing to do with the values obtained with python code. This model (yolo v3 tiny) is to detect objects in images and I've constated that the values obtained with python code are the correct ones

Why do I get different outputs in android? Do I have to do something special to run model in android? Do I have to do something different in model conversion from H5 to tflite?

NOTE: version of tensorflow in google colab is 1.14.0. In android I use this version of tflite `org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:1.14.0`

**Updated**

I've tried with an input array of ones in both cases (python and android) to be sure that the input data is the same and the results vary:

```
 Python results    |  Android results
 0 >   0.06118933  |  0 >   0.061190486
 1 > - 0.50384498  |  1 > - 0.50384396
 2 > - 0.30500048  |  2 > - 0.30500013
 3 > - 0.18725708  |  3 > - 0.18725668
 4 > -12.56872463  |  4 > -12.568727
 5 > - 3.53239870  |  5 > - 3.5323968
 6 >   0.26756036  |  6 >   0.26756087
 7 > - 0.63708508  |  7 > - 0.6370841
 8 > - 0.11959708  |  8 > - 0.119596675
 9 > - 0.42219949  |  9 > - 0.42219883
10 > -12.26699734  | 10 > -12.266998
11 > - 3.42504168  | 11 > - 3.4250417
12 >   0.29714739  | 12 >   0.2971481
13 > - 0.76750284  | 13 > - 0.7675022
14 > - 0.13859260  | 14 > - 0.13859189
15 > - 0.02096577  | 15 > - 0.020965554
16 > -12.78137684  | 16 > -12.781382
17 > - 3.34643984  | 17 > - 3.3464384
```

Comment: Could these differences be due to the use of primitive java float in the android code?

From what I have seen, tflite does not support the use of BigDecimal. One way to resolve these differences would be by quantization of the model?

Comment: Seems like those differences are normal. After correcting some bug in the code I have been able to verify that these differences do not alter the final result once processed the output of the model.

Comment: Could you tell me what that bug was? Pulling my hair out stuck with the same issue for last 3 days.

Comment: The first bug was iterating the output vectors of the TFLITE model. YOLOv3 Tiny has two outputs o sizes 8x8 and 16x16 when the input has 256x256 size. However I had the same for (with the same limit) to iterate both outputs. It was a copy+paste bug.And also, at the beginning I was also comparing badly the python results and the Android ones (the comparison in this question is ok). This was because in the python implementation there was a function that modified an input and I was using that modified input to compare with the Android one (unmodified).